# Trigger javascript from button

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have done this code in order to have email opt-in form when the video ends.
What I would like to know is how I call this html from `onClick` button. The whole idea is to click a button and call this code into a lightbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <style>
            #overlayContactForm {
                visibility: hidden;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                text-align:center;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
            #overlayContactForm div {
                width: 428px;
                margin: 65px;
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                padding: 15px;
                text-align: center;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
        <div align="center">
            <script>
                // create youtube player
                var player;
                function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                    player = new YT.Player('player', {
                        height: '390',
                        width: '640',
                        videoId: 'VhvUEhxL1DQ',
                        playerVars: {rel: 0},
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }

                // autoplay video
                function onPlayerReady(event) {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                }

                // when video ends
                function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
                    if(event.data === 0) {            
                        // $('#lightbox-panel').lightBox();
                        el = document.getElementById("overlayContactForm");
                        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : 
                        "visible";
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="overlayContactForm">
            <div>
                <h1> Mobivate</h1>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3"   
                        placeholder="Email Address">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                </form>
                <p> Testing email opt-in - Video/Form </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: you can have an onclick event call your function. like this: <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>. though it's not clear to me form this which function would actually start the video.

Comment: The fact that you give us the code you want in the lightbox doesn't help explain what steps you've actually taken to solve the problem. What have you tried? You reference `onclick` in your question--have you tried attaching a function to the button's `onclick` handler or an event listener?

Comment: @Palpatim I wouldn't be asking for help if I would know the next steps .

Comment: @BenMarch what I would like to have is a button to call my video inside a lightbox

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the video to play when the user clicks the submit button. You can try something like this:

```
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3"   
                    placeholder="Email Address">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Then create a JS function to handle the submit:

```
function onSubmit() {
    player.playVideo();
    return false;
}
```

I added "return false;" here so that the page won't refresh, but you will want to handle that properly. You could have an onclick on the button instead of an onsubmit on the form, but it depends on how you want to handle it.

Comment: I have done some progress by using a different approach. I have post another question here on stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172470/javascript-email-opt-in-form-event-on-youtube-api) you probably can easily help me . Cheers